# Refactoring function and better promise chaining

Tags: javascript, promise

I currently have this function and it works:

```js
function waitForObjectProperty(object, property) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, property, {
            configurable: true,
            set: function(value) {
                Object.defineProperty(object, property, {
                    value: value,
                });
                resolve(object[property]);
            },
        });
    });
}

waitForObjectProperty(window, "google").then(function(object) {
    waitForObjectProperty(object, "maps").then(function(object) {
        waitForObjectProperty(object, "places").then(function(object) {
            console.log('places object:', google.maps.places);
        });
    });
});


setTimeout(function(){ window.google = {} }, 1000);
setTimeout(function(){ window.google.maps = {} }, 2000);
setTimeout(function(){ window.google.maps.places = {} }, 3000);
```

.. but I was wondering how can I could improve it so I don't have to chain promises every time I have to check for a nested object?

Comment: do you mean like `waitForObjectProperty(window, "google")
.then(object => waitForObjectProperty(object, "maps"))
.then(object => waitForObjectProperty(object, "places"))
.then(object =>console.log('places object:', google.maps.places));`

Comment: Are you able to use ES8 syntax? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: `async/await` is much simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The benefits of the method shown below is that its usage is a single line of code and, maybe more importantly, the "path" can be dynamically created

A brief explanation

The path (after the "root" - `window` in your case) is a string in dot notation, so first split that string into parts

With the resulting array, use the array.reduce method to make the chain of promises - the "seed" to array.reduce is `Promise.resolve(root)` and each subsequent promise resolves (as in your code) to the "created" object

Sure the "supporting" code is bigger, but the end result is as simple as

```
waitForNestedObject(window, 'some.very.long.path.that.you.can.even.build.dynamically.if.you.want');
```

```js
function waitForNestedObject(root, objectPath) {
    var waitForObjectProperty = function (object, property) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, property, {
                configurable: true,
                set: function(value) {
                    Object.defineProperty(object, property, {
                        value: value,
                    });
                    resolve(object[property]);
                },
            });
        });
    }
    var steps = objectPath.split('.');
    return steps.reduce(function(p, step) {
        return p.then(function(object) {
            return waitForObjectProperty(object, step);
        });
    }, Promise.resolve(root));
}
//
// use is simple now
//
waitForNestedObject(window, 'google.maps.places')
.then(function(object) {
    console.log(object);
});

setTimeout(function(){ window.google = {} }, 1000);
setTimeout(function(){ window.google.maps = {} }, 2000);
setTimeout(function(){ window.google.maps.places = {hello:'world'} }, 3000);
```

> In modern javascript you can write it like the following - *(not sure why you can't use modern javascript (as per comment in another answer regarding arrow functions))*

```js
const waitForNestedObject = (root, objectPath) => {
    const waitForObjectProperty = (object, property) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, property, {
        configurable: true,
        set: function(value) {
            Object.defineProperty(object, property, {
                value: value,
            });
            resolve(object[property]);
        },
    }));
    return objectPath.split('.').reduce((p, step) => p.then(object => waitForObjectProperty(object, step)), Promise.resolve(root));
};
//
// usage remains the same
waitForNestedObject(window, 'google.maps.places')
.then(object => console.log(object));

setTimeout(function(){ window.google = {} }, 1000);
setTimeout(function(){ window.google.maps = {} }, 2000);
setTimeout(function(){ window.google.maps.places = {hello:'world'} }, 3000);
```

Comment: Can't use modern JS cause IE11 and no babel :) But thanks heaps for the answer, just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

```
const tapProp = property => object => waitForObjectProperty(object, property);

Promise.resolve(window)
  .then(tapProp("google"))
  .then(tapProp("maps"))
  .then(tapProp("places"))
  .then(function(object) {
    console.log('places object:', google.maps.places);
  });
```

Comment: Don't I have to `bind` to be able to pass extra params?

Comment: @3zzy Nop. This technique is called `currying`, behaves kinda like `bind`, but different thing.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function waitForObjectProperty(object, property) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, property, {
            configurable: true,
            set: function(value) {
                Object.defineProperty(object, property, {
                    value: value,
                });
                resolve(object[property]);
            },
        });
    });
}
// you can just return promise and then chainning
waitForObjectProperty(window, "google")
    .then(object => waitForObjectProperty(object, "maps"))
    .then(object => waitForObjectProperty(object, "places"))
    .then(object => console.log('places object:', google.maps.places));


setTimeout(function(){ window.google = {} }, 1000);
setTimeout(function(){ window.google.maps = {} }, 2000);
setTimeout(function(){ window.google.maps.places = {} }, 3000);
```

Comment: Thats what I'm doing right? Just can't use the arrow functions.

Comment: no, you have nested .then's @3zzy - this is a .then chain - but that isn't what you meant in the question is it